# How can I change the mount point path while using udisks?

Tags: 13.04, mount, udisks

How I can mount my disk with udisks to `/media/$USER/%disk_title%` instead of to `/media/%disk_title%`?

When I try this:

```
udisks --mount /dev/sda1
```

It mounts to `/media/%disk_title%`, but in GUI (file manager left-side panel), it mounts to `/media/$USER/%disk_title%`, how I can do this in terminal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda4
$ udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/sda4
```