# Why did Files (Nautilus) stop updating partition's bookmarks?

Tags: nautilus, 13.10, files, bookmarks

I've upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and noticed that Files (Nautilus) stopped updating my bookmarks that are located in another partition (an ext4 one). It used to work before.

Testing, I've found out that, if I add any new bookmark (using `CTRL + D`, for example), Files then adds this new one and updates all bookmarks, showing that ones that point to my partition. I conclude that the feature (updating bookmarks) works, but it's not being executed when I mount my partition clicking on it.

Any hints on how to solve this? Bookmarks really speed up everyday activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that this is a known bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1246493

Despite not showing up in the nautilus bookmark pane, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/293910/175159), you can still quickly access bookmarks by right-clicking on the nautilus icon and bookmarks will be displayed as a quicklist:

[image]

But I've figured out a workaround. Would Nautilus show my bookmarks if I set my partition to be mounted at Ubuntu startup time? Yes, it would. :-)

Beware that Ubuntu mounts partitions at `/media/yourusername/partitionname` when you mount them by clicking on them. So, your bookmarks will point to this location. When I tested mounting my partition using `udisks` command, it mounted at `/media/partitionname`. Searching has brought this solution:

[How can I change the mount point path while using udisks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299298/how-can-i-change-the-mount-point-path-while-using-udisks)

**Resume: Set your partition to be mounted at startup, at `Startup Applications` on Ubuntu, using this command:**

`udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdaY` (change **Y** to your partition number!)

Now my partition's bookmarks are displayed correctly.

For the ones who don't know how to add a command to be executed at startup time, I recommend reading [Ubuntu documentation on Auto Mount Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions), section **Per-User Mounts**, subsection **Adding to startup**. Section **Finding the device name of your Partition** explains how to find your device name (the `/dev/sdaY` in my example above).